# Dagger 2 : ImagesRepo cannot be provided without @Inject constructor or @Provides

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I provide `ImagesRepo` using `RepoModule`, ImgesReo depends on `RxApiController`  and `SharePreferenceHelper` and i am providing these dependencies in  `RepoModule` itself, these dependencies comes from `AppModule`.

```
@Module(includes = AppModule.class)
public class RepoModule {

    @Provides
    @Inject
    public ImagesRepo providesImagesRepo(RxApiController rxApiController, SharePreferenceHelper sharePreferenceHelper) {
        return new ImagesRepo(rxApiController, sharePreferenceHelper);
    }
}
```

When i try to inject `ImagesRepo` like this

```
@Inject
    public ImagesRepo imagesRepo;


    public MyActivityViewmodelImpl() {
        MyApplication.getRepoComponent().inject(this);
    }
```

It shows error if i remove `@Inject` from constructor of `ImagesRepo`, I think that i am providing `RxApiController` and  `SharePreferenceHelper` from `RepoModule`

```
@Inject
public ImagesRepo(RxApiController rxApiController, SharePreferenceHelper sharePreferenceHelper) {
    super(rxApiController, sharePreferenceHelper);
}
```

Question is why i am suppose to add `@Inject` at `ImagesRepo` constructor, if i am providing dependencies for `ImagesRepo` in `RepoModule` itself

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors and confusion you should make sure to understand what each annotation does. A `@Provides` method does *not* need an `@Inject` annotation. Here, you could even use constructor injection alone, and you wouldn't need the `@Provides` method (or the module) at all, reducing the amount of boilerplate needed.

As to your specific error, I would guess that you either don't add `RepoModule` to your component, or that you try to inject your class with the wrong component (that does not have access to `RepoModule`).

---

Adding `@Inject` on the constructor of `ImagesRepo` will mark it for constructor injection so that Dagger can and will create it *for you*. There is no need for the module (that you didn't add / component can't access), which is why it will "work" when you do so.

To avoid confusion and errors either use a `@Provides` method from a module *or* use constructor injection—preferrably constructor injection which will eliminate the boilerplate, which is one of the reasons why you'd use Dagger in the first place.